# How to get blueprint class name in C++ in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I want to get the name of the blueprint class so I can compare the actors,
[I want this Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hCqH.png)
But GetName() just gives me the one in the world, for example I get BP_Block_IronOre_193

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
GetClass()->GetName();
```

To get the class' full name.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetClass()->GetDisplayNameText().ToString()
```